# 2008 Chevrolet Express ABS module component

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

Can anyone please help me identify what this component is, and if there is any alternative I can use to replace it? It got corroded.

I got it out of a brake control module of a Chevrolet van.

[image: Picture of the component]

Comment: Please also add a picture of the circuit board area that this part came out from. This will help narrow it down. It is almost certainly a diode, but whether it's a basic silicon rectifier or a power Schottky would be dictated by where in the circuitry it is. Also please supply the measurements of the plastic case of the diode - just width and length, including the terminals.

Comment: Hmmm fiddeling with a brake controller. Brave.

Comment: Test it with a DMM in diode mode

Comment: Logo is Vishay...

Answer (score 3):

The [manufacturer logo](http://www.ecadata.de/herst/myshowlogo.php?F_SPRACHE=2) is Vishay. The package appears to be a DO-214. The two letters on many Vishay diodes correspond to the first and last letter of the part number.

From this information I determined that it is a [GF1D](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88617/gf1.pdf) silicon rectifier diode, rated at 1 A and 200 V.